# How to Set FailFastRetryStrategy and Avoid Infinite Retry Loop in Couchbase-Spark Connector?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, couchbase, retry-logic

I am working with Couchbase-Spark Connector (couchbase-spark-connector) and facing an issue where if the Couchbase instance is not running or gets disconnected while the Spark job is running, the application enters into an infinite retry loop. I have observed that the retry mechanism keeps trying to reconnect to Couchbase, causing the logs to get flooded with TimeoutException and EndpointConnectionFailedEvent errors. Here's a snippet of the logs for reference:

```
[info] 15:14:46.305|WARN | com.couchbase.endpoint [...] TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 1000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured)
[info] 15:14:47.322|WARN | com.couchbase.endpoint [...] Connect attempt 1 failed because of TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 1000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured)
...
[info] 15:14:47.322|WARN | com.couchbase.endpoint [...] Connect attempt 100 failed because of TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 1000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured)
```

I suspect that this behavior is controlled by the retry strategy. By default, Couchbase-Spark Connector uses BestEffortRetryStrategy, which seems to cause this infinite retry loop. I'd like to change this to FailFastRetryStrategy to avoid such a scenario and ensure that the job fails fast if Couchbase is not reachable.

I tried setting the retry strategy in the Spark Configuration like so:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
.setAppName("test")
.set("spark.couchbase.retryStrategy", "FailFastRetry")
```

However, this results in an error:

```
Caused by: com.couchbase.client.core.error.InvalidArgumentException: Expected a value Jackson can bind to interface com.couchbase.client.core.retry.RetryStrategy but got "FailFastRetry".
```

How can I correctly set FailFastRetryStrategy in Couchbase-Spark Connector to avoid this infinite retry loop and ensure that my Spark job fails fast when Couchbase is not accessible?

Comment: It appears that that the possible values for the. Enum RetryStragegy are exponential, linear and constant. 

I'm wondering if instead the configuration would be RetrySpecification.  

    /**
     * Creates a new retry specification, usually called from jackson.
     */ 
    @JsonCreator
    public RetrySpecification(
      @JsonProperty("strategy") RetryStrategy strategy,
      @JsonProperty("interval") int interval,
      @JsonProperty("after") int after,
      @JsonProperty("max-duration") int maxDuration,
      @JsonProperty("ceil") int ceil) {...}